# USB-C network switch

Tags: networking, switch, usb-c

I'm planning to build a Linux computing cluster (I already have 4 PCs more or less ready for the job) and I was wondering if there are any network switches which use USB-C cables instead of fiber/normal cat X cables? (I'm asking this because USB-C speeds are approaching the speeds of SFP+/cat6 cables)

Note: most of my google searches return KVM switches or docking stations  and I'm not interested in these.

Comment: Note that while USB2 has a max distance of 4m, USB3.2Gen2 is only 1m.  In my opinion it's best to use the stuff it is intended for.

Comment: USB is specified to use a Host and Device connection. It cannot work in a network type architecture.

Comment: Thank you @Alphy13

Comment: 1) Thunderbolt/USB4 defines a host to host networking protocol  2) Areca has SAN-in-a-box devices which allow connecting multiple computers over Thunderbolt. Generic networking as Alphy13 correctly notes is not possible.

Comment: Thank you guys!